# Create mysql-view with parameter

Tags: mysql, view, parameters

This is my first table **t1**:

```
-----------------------------
| code | month      | value |
-----------------------------
| 101  |august      | 1     |
| 101  |September   | 3     |
| 101  |November    | 7     |
| 202  |august      | 5     |
| 202  |September   | 6     |
| 202  |November    | 9     |
| 303  |august      | 9     |
| 303  |September   | 3     |
-----------------------------
```

I want to create the second table **t2** (view table) looks like

```
------------------------------------------
| code | month      | value | value_begin |
------------------------------------------
| 101  |august      | 1     |0            |
| 101  |September   | 3     |1            |
| 101  |November    | 7     |4 (3+1)      |
| 202  |august      | 5     |0            |
| 202  |September   | 6     |5            |
| 202  |November    | 2     |11 (6+5)     |
| 303  |august      | 9     |0            |
| 303  |september   | 3     |9            |
-------------------------------------------
```

value_begin is sum value and value_begin above the row, like in row 101-November value_begin is 4 from value 3 (above) and value_begin 1 (above).

Is this possible to create the second table t2 in view?

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is the SQLFIddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48d7/1)**

**Below is the View showed in Demo :**

```
Create View V1 as
select T1.code,T1.Month,T1.Value,
       sum(IFNULL(T2.value,0)) as value_begin
  from Table1 T1
 left join Table1 T2
    On T1.code = T2.code 
   and month(str_to_date(substring(T1.month,1,3),'%b')) > month(str_to_date(substring(T2.month,1,3),'%b'))
Group by T1.code,T1.Month,T1.Value 
Order by t1.code,month(str_to_date(substring(T1.month,1,3),'%b'))
;
```

Adding variable is not allowed hence my previous approach was not helpful. And you needed variable in view that is also not possible. Here I used the logic of your table to overcome the situation. Hope this helps. Please revert back if any query.

---

Note : I have added few rows in demo for checking the calculation validation.

Comment: i think sub-query doesn't work with mysql-view. but thanks anyway

Comment: @StefanusDaniel : I have modified my solution. Check it and letme know if it is not working